# R RODBC SAP HANA Calloc could not allocate memory by sqlQuery

Tags: r, hana, rodbc, sles

I have a SAP HANA server, and a SLES 11 server running R 2.15 and R studio server.

I am able to communicate from the SLES server to the HANA server via ODBC using isql with no problem.

I connect from R using RODBC and a connection string:

```
    library(RODBC)
    ch <- odbcDriverConnect("DSN=hana;SERVERNODE=HDB.IP.ADD.RES:30015;UID=MYUSER;PWD=****")
```

So far so good but when trying to run sqlQuery I get the following error:

> a <- sqlQuery(ch,"SELECT TOP 100 *, F FROM "SOME_HANA_TABLE"")
>
> Error in odbcQuery(channel, query, rows_at_time) :
>
> Calloc could not allocate memory (18446744073709551616 of 22816 bytes)

At first glance I thought the query table was too big but that is not the case since I am asking only for the top 100 rows. I have searched the internet and only found this [link](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-sig-db/2012q2/001195.html) in the R mailing list which suggest to reinstall RODBC. I will give it a try, but I'm not so confident in it working...

Has anyone encountered this error? Have you been able to overcome it?

Note: I have been able to connect to the HANA server from my local windows machine using the code mentioned above. So I think the error has to do with how RODBC intercats with the SLES HANA drivers... or something like that.

Edit: Tried reinstalling RODBC, did not work, error persist.

Comment: You can trying setting `rows_at_time = 1` but that may not work

Comment: I have tried that. Didn´t work :(

Comment: R 2.15 is pretty old - have you tried this with a newer release?

Comment: I know its old but is the version SAP recomends for integration with SAP HANA. I have succeeded using R 3.3 and windows 7.